# looping script over factors

Tags: python, string, loops

I have a large py script and at the beginning of it I have to enter a variable.

For example:

```
year = "2015"
# yellow red orange pink  
color= "yellow"

in_folder = r"E:/test/" + year + "/03_lines/" + color

...
```

Instead of running the script manually for each of the color, I would like to have a loop doing it automatically for me. But since I am new with python, I really don´t know how to deal with it.

If I create a string `color= ['yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'pink']` and I loop `for i in color:`, should it be ok?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `w1`? Do you mean `for i in color`? It should be ok, but you can make you variable names more explicit, for examples: `colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'pink']`, then `for color in colors:` and finally (inside the for loop) `in_folder = "E:/test/" + year + "/03_lines/" + color`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post ;). I will try this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
year = ["2014", "2015"]
# yellow red orange pink
color=  ['yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'pink']
for each_year in year:
    for each_color in color:
        in_folder = r"E:/test/" + each_year + "/03_lines/" + each_color
        [rest of the script]
```

Yes you can use for loop for iteration like `for i in color:`

Comment: I did not know about the "each_" in front the string name. Thanks!

Comment: @Floni: the `each_` has no syntactic meaning here, Mahesh just found that the identifier name was clearer that way, but it could be `for current_year in year: ...`

Comment: I think I have an issue with the list of colors... I have the errorIndentation `Error: Expeected an indented block` after `n_folder = r"E:/test/" + each_year + "/03_lines/" + each_color`

Answer (score 0):

You can do in one line without loop :

```
year = ["2014", "2015"]
color=  ['yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'pink']

print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y:r"E:/test/" + x + "/03_lines/" + y,color)),year)))
```

or if you want you can use list comprehension:

```
[r"E:/test/" + item + "/03_lines/" + sub_item for item in color for sub_item in color]
```

Above list comprehension is same as:

```
final_list=[]

for item in color:
    for sub_item in year:
        final_list.append(r"E:/test/" + item + "/03_lines/" + sub_item)

print(final_list)
```

output:

```
['E:/test/yellow/03_lines/2014', 'E:/test/yellow/03_lines/2015', 'E:/test/red/03_lines/2014', 'E:/test/red/03_lines/2015', 'E:/test/orange/03_lines/2014', 'E:/test/orange/03_lines/2015', 'E:/test/pink/03_lines/2014', 'E:/test/pink/03_lines/2015']
```

Comment: But what is `year` and `color` here? Based on OP's code, this would loop characters in strings.

Comment: Thanks for this but since the rest of the code is quite long, I prefer to do a simple loop :)

Comment: @Floni long ? its one line shorter than other answers.

Comment: @Floni no issue.